# Manga where the main character sees the group of heroes defeating the demon king, gets stabbed in the back and reborn into his younger self

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's been practically a month since I began searching to find it again. Basically it's a manga where the main character is a soldier in the army of his kingdom, he helps the hero team to defeat the demon king.

Just after defeating the demon king he got stabbed in the back by some monster and got reborn into his younger self.

The main character is a little boy with all his memories from the past and experience as a warrior, his father is known to be the strongest warrior in the kingdom at the time, his father is guarding a forest where monsters lives.

One day, his father takes him and another boy from the village to exercise in the forest and they encounter a giant fox beast. The beast casts a spell and is stopped by the boy who talks to the beast and convince him not to destroy the whole forest.

Later on we learn that the main character, in his past life has suffered human experimentation. Forgot to say, he got a cringe but powerful spirit which has the appearence of a cringe young girl in him which attribute is dark magic. By CRINGE i mean that despite her young appearence she is very scary she gives the feelings that she can see through you, a litle bit like litle girl with red hair in "Against the gods".

So the main character goes to military/magic school because he met another litle girl which happened to be the headmaster of a magic academy.

And in the last chapters I can remember, the main character and his group of friend are send to the vanguard of the forest his father is guarding for training.

The little sister of his best friend got lost in the forest, so everyone is looking for her. They find her, but also find a dragon.

After getting almost killed by the dragon his best friend also gets his personal litle girm spirit within him which heals him.

They go into some strange door and see the memories of the past life of the main character when for exemple a group of ravaged his village killed the girl he loved and when his best friend tried to kill a high demon he got beheaded (his head got cut).

When his best friends which is with him at the moment sees his memories,he understands the situation.

They go out of the ''cave''i would say, and are confronted with the drake.

This is as far as i read.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are looking for *[Hiraheishi wa Kako wo Yumemiru.](https://myanimelist.net/manga/98712/Hiraheishi_wa_Kako_wo_Yumemiru)*

The first chapter is showing the dark future where they get to the fight with the demon lord, then the moment the demon lord is defeated, the main character, John, gets stabbed through the back and dies.  Then he is back as a baby in his crib confused as to what just happened.

In the third chapter, his father takes him and another boy from the village into the forest where they encounter a crystal wolf.  After the father attacks the wolf, it starts to cast its chain lightning spell.  John then rushes towards the wolf as his father tries to run away with the two boys.  He then convinces the wolf they mean no harm and the two of them end up making a pact to help each other and leave each other in peace.

Jumping ahead, the most recent chapter on the site i read has them fighting the dragon, with the evil spirit girl and a couple of his friends.

I just skimmed through the first few chapters and last one, but i have read through it before and I think the rest also matches.

Comment: Yessss that s it thank you Shufly !!!

Comment: @GonFreecs: Don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @shufly: Was this just one you knew from experience, or did you do a search? :) I'm always happy to learn new search techniques.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I had read it before and enjoyed it, so my search method was looking through my bookmarks until i found it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[Tsuyokute New Saga](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-261966)*:

> The Demon King led his army of demons to wipe out the human race. The Hero, Kail, and his allies attacked the Demon King's castle to defeat the Demon King. The Demon King is slain, but at what cost? Kail lost all of his allies throughout the war. Friends, family, lovers, comrades. All dead, and he is dying.
>
> As Kail's life ebbs away in the Demon King's chamber, he notices a strange gem that the Demon King had coveted and approaches this relic to grab it; after an intense light glows, he is sent years into the past. After recovering from the initial shock, now in his younger body, he decides to avoid making the same mistakes of his first time through these years and to become stronger.

Found with a search for `manga "demon king" stabbed reborn`

Comment: It's very alike but it ain't this one either