# Manga where the main character travels back in time after being stabbed by his companions

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga was in color, I believe. At the beginning the main character is a guy who is trying to get help because his sister was poisoned, but he gets stabbed by his companions and goes back in time to his younger self. It was set in an apocalypse era and I think his hair color was black.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: @DavidW i had read this like  2 years ago i think and where, i dont recall im sorry that this was not as helpful as you would like

Comment: What sort of time period was the story set in? And do you recall the hair colour of any of the main characters?

Comment: Might it be the same one as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221666/manga-where-the-main-character-sees-the-group-of-heroes-defeating-the-demon-king?rq=1?

Comment: @LogicDictates it was set in a apocalypse era and i think the hair color was black

Comment: @FuzzyBoots im sorry but it is not due to it starting with the main character trying to receive help to get aid for his sister but ends up i guess betrayed and then dies then returns to younger self

Comment: A correct answer can be accepted by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Endgame Restart*](https://m.webnovel.com/comic/endgame-restart_20785512706975201) by Rose Studio

> Yang Fan saw his younger sister die in front of him and his girlfriend betrayed him. But he got lucky and was reborn before the Apocalypse. In the previous life, he was humiliated and betrayed. But this time, he clenches the superpower ring and says: "Only the strongest one deserves to survive, and I am the strongest one!"

[image: Image of Yang Fan cradling his sister]

[image: Yang Fan stabbed]

[image: Ysng Fan reborn]

Found with a search for `manga sister poisoned stabbed reborn`